# How to wrap text in block, using Ember js and Handlebars js?

Tags: ember.js, wrapper, handlebars.js, helper

I want to wrap some text in block. Cannot figure out how to do it.

JS:

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('mywrap', function (options) {
      return '<p class="TEST" >' + options.fn(this) + '</p>';
    });
```

Template:

```
    {{#mywrap}}
        This text must be wrapped
    {{/mywrap}}
```

Final html should be like this:

```
<p class="TEST">This text must be wrapped</p>
```

Ember v1.0.0-pre4,
Handlebars 1.0.rc.2, 
Jquery 1.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways of wrapping text in a block, really depends on your usecase.
I'm assuming for some reason, literally writing the HTML is not what you're looking for.

Firstly, you can just return a Handlebars SafeString, however this presents a security issue if you are wrapping user-provided content.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('mywrap', function (options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString('<p class="TEST" >' + options.fn(this) + '</p>';)
});
```

Secondly, you can wrap it in a view

```
{{#view classNames="TEST" tagName="p"}}
  This text must be wrapped
{{/view}}
```

Thirdly, you can create a handlebars helper that creates a view.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('mywrap', function (options) {
  var view = Ember.View.extend({tagName:"p",classNames:"TEST"})
  return Ember.Handlebars.helper.view.call(this, view, options)
});
```

Caveat, I haven't actually checked the code so there may be typos